# Need to write one sql script to find the metadata details of any database in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

My aim is to write a script in Oracle using PL/SQL to fetch the data from the database tables in the below format.

```
table_name|table_size|avg_row_length
```

This I need for all the tables available in the database. The below is the script which am trying to write to fetch the above details for specific schema. However am getting below error

> PLS-00103 : Encountered the symbol "AVG_ROW_SIZE" when expecting one of the following:
>   := ; not null default charec

```
SET serveroutput on;
clear screen;

set lin 20000;
set trimspool on;
set feed off;
set verify off;
set head off;

spool &&1..metadata_report.out

DECLARE
    v_tbl_name   VARCHAR2(1500);
    v_row_num    NUMBER(20);
    table_size   NUMBER(20);
    avg_row_size NUMBER(30);
    CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT DISTINCT table_name
      FROM   all_tables
      WHERE  owner = Upper('&&1')
      ORDER  BY table_name ASC;
    c1_rec       c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;

    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO c1_rec;

        exit WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'select sum((bytes/1024)) from user_extents where segment_name = "'||c1_rec.table_name||'"' INTO
table_size;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'select decode(count(*),NULL,0, count(*)) FROM &&1.."'||c1_rec.table_name||'"'
    INTO v_row_num;

IF( v_row_num = 0 ) THEN
  avg_row_size := 0;
ELSE
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT table_size/v_row_num FROM DUAL' INTO avg_row_size;
END IF;

dbms_output.Put_line(c1_rec.table_name
                     ||'|'
                     ||table_size
                     ||'|'
                     ||avg_row_size);
END LOOP;

CLOSE c1;
END; 

/
```

Comment: It should not be a problem pasting your scripts - use ctrl+K to add code to your posts. At least you can name the tables you are querying.

Comment: somehow i added the script..pls help me now..

Comment: What are your requirements?  You're querying `all_tables` but then hitting `user_extents`.  Are you assuming that this script will be run as the user that owns the tables?  Or to you want to run it for all the tables in a particular schema that may not be the current user's schema?  Define the size of a table?  Should we exclude the `LOB` segments associated with the table?  The overflow area for an IOT?  Define the average size of a row.  Do you merely want to define it as the size of the table segment divided by the number of rows in the table?

Comment: yes...i can use all_extents also..i want to give owner as input to the file...thats i gave &&1. we can exclude lob........oit not required.....yes

Answer (score 2):

Given the error, and without seeing your script, my guess is that you are trying to get this information from `DBA_TABLES` and that you want to use the `AVG_ROW_LEN` column but have typed the name incorrectly as `AVG_ROW_SIZE`.  My guess is that you are trying to write the query

```
SELECT table_name, num_rows * avg_row_len, avg_row_len
  FROM dba_tables
```

Be aware, however, that the data in `DBA_TABLES` may be incorrect.  At best, it is an approximation of the state of the table the last time that statistics were gathered on the table.  But it is entirely possible that statistics were never gathered on the table.  Or that statistics were gathered when the table had a very small amount of data and now it has billions of rows.  For many situations, though, it's reasonable to assume that the statistics are reasonably accurate and that these approximate values will be close enough.  Of course, you'd really want to add the `OWNER` column to the query since there can be many different tables with the same name in a single database.

You may also get tripped up by definitions.  The "average row length" of a table or the "size of a table" can mean very different things to different people.  What happens, for example, if your table contains an out-of-line `LOB`?  Do you count the size of the `LOB` when you are calculating the size of the table since the `LOB` is not stored in the table's segment?  Does the average row length change if you add a million empty blocks to your table?  It does if you want to define it as the size of the table divided by the number of rows.  It doesn't if you want to define it as the average amount of data that would be returned if you fetched one row of data from the table.

If you want more accuracy, you can use the `DBA_SEGMENTS` table to get the size of the various segments on disk.  Depending on your definitions, though, you may need to use other data dictionary tables like `DBA_LOBS` to figure out which LOB segments are related to a particular table in order to include them in the calculation for the size of the table.  You can use the `DBMS_SPACE` package to get information about the amount of empty space in the table should you want to back that out.  If you want to get an accurate count of the number of rows in the table, you'd need to do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name` which would potentially be quite expensive.

Comment: can email you the script which am writing now. which can give you more understanding. can u pls provide me your email add? bcz for me format is more important and I want to write the out put to test file. i know that the values in the dba_tables is not accurate so i need the good values..bcz am going to fetch production data and going to use use this as an input for one of my other script...kindly help me if possible..

Comment: @SrikanthGoudLingaala - Feel free to edit your post to include your script.  That way other people, not just me, can look at it.  If you want more accurate results, you'll also need to edit your question to include the precise definition of "table size" and "average row length" that you want to use.

Comment: added the script now..pls correct me or let me know if i can write even better..the above script giving error...i need some script in that formart..i think you got my requirement.

Comment: @Srikanth Goud Lingaala - did you get your answer from Justin? And why all that dynamic SQL needed in your code? Why using '&&1' in PL/SQL? This is wrong, the substitution parameters to be used in SQL only...

Comment: i still did not get ny ans... if my script is wrong..can u pls help me in writing correct 1? i think u got my requirement.....n to give input as schema name am using th &&1

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example of calc avg row len: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_average_row_length.htm
You can add the rest... No need for PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the table_size, you should sum up all blocks allocated instead of multiplying the average row length calculated and the number of rows based on statistics created. Just think about non reused blocks or tables with a huge number of deletes (among other things). [This and other database related information needed for optimisation is available in QueryAdvisor.](http://www.queryadvisor.com/)